# Avoid sorting in SQL Server

Tags: t-sql, sorting, sql-server-2012, row-number

How can I avoid sorting.
I have a dynamic sql query and I pass in the  sort text into query. In the below query what should I pass to achieve no sorting.

```
DECLARE @sql varchar(max)
    SET @sql = 'SELECT a.num AS Num, a.photo as Photo, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (' + @SortBy + ') AS RowNumber FROM tbl a (nolock) WHERE a.num IN (' + @NumList + ') '
```

Note : I tried `ORDER BY (SELECT 0)` and also `ORDER BY (SELECT null)` still the result I get is in Asc order.

Comment: Please show the execution plan. Also what are you using the row number for?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to order by whatever the primary key is.  I am assuming that is your clustered index.

Comment: If I pass 001,009,098,877,723,243,010 in to the @NumList param the results returned should be in the same order.

Comment: I don't think you can do that with the query you have.  You will need a different query